# Installation of libgsl01dbl:i386 on 64 bit machine

Tags: 12.04, libraries

I am trying to install 32 bit versions of `libgsl01dbl:i386` and `libgsl0-dev:386` on an Ubuntu 64 (12.04).  I read that by doing `sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev:386` that it would automatically place the libraries in the lib32 directory and that it could coexist with the fact that the 64 bits are installed in lib.  The reason I want to do this is to build .so files that can operate in 32 bit machines; while also still being able to make 64 bit ones here.

When I attempted to do it, I received a message indicating that the already installed 64 bit ones would first be uninstalled before the 32 bit ones were installed.

Is there something special about libgsl that causes this, or am I doing something wrong?  I have been able to do this with other libraries in the past.

Comment: Try this method: http://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/